# Solving $ \ln \left(e^x+1\right)-\ln \left(e^x-1\right)=x $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently stuck on a problem involving logarithmic equations and would appreciate any help that you could provide.

The equation I'm working on is:
$$
\ln \left(e^x+1\right)-\ln \left(e^x-1\right)=x
$$

I'm supposed to then find the sum of the solutions of the equation.

I've attempted to solve the equation by applying the logarithmic identity:
$$
\ln \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\ln (a)-\ln (b)
$$
which gives:
$$
\ln \left(\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}\right)=x
$$

From here, I exponentiated both sides using the property:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& e^{\ln (x)}=x, \\
& \text { to get: } \\
& \frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}=e^x
\end{aligned}
$$
Then, I cross-multiplied and simplified the expression to get:
$$
e^{2 x}-2e^x-1=0
$$

At this point, I tried to use the quadratic formula to solve for $e^x$, but I got stuck with a messy expression that I couldn't simplify.

So, I'm turning to you for help. Can you suggest another method for solving this equation? And once the solution is found, can you also tell me how to find the sum of all its solutions?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You've done all the hard work. The quadratic formula should finish the job for you. The roots of that equation are the golden mean and its reciprocal. Then take the logarithm.

Comment: $\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}=e^x \implies e^{2 x}-2e^x-1=0$ which is not quite what you wrote.

Comment: @Henry I edited it, noticed the mistake. However, I'm still stuck at that point. According to Wolfram, the answer should be x = log(1+√2).

Comment: Good work so far! ... What's the "messy expression" you obtained from the Quadratic Formula? The roots of $y^2-2y-1=0$ don't seem too bad to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if $y = e^x$, then $y^2 - 2y - 1 = 0$, and completing the square gives
$$0 = y^2 - 2y - 1 = y^2 - 2y + 1 - 2 = (y-1)^2 - 2.$$
Hence $$(y-1)^2 = 2$$ or $$y - 1 = \pm \sqrt{2},$$ therefore $$y = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}.$$
Since we stated that $y = e^x$, this means $e^x$ is either $1 - \sqrt{2}$ or $1 + \sqrt{2}$.  But the first case is impossible since $e^x > 0$ for any real number $x$, and $1 - \sqrt{2} < 0$.

The rest follows trivially.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have another method for solving, but you made an algebra mistake. Going from
$$\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1} = e^x$$
You should end up with
$$(e^{x})^2-2e^x-1 = 0$$
Using the quadratic formula and simplify we find
$$e^x = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}$$
If we are solving over $\mathbb{R}$ then we take the positive square root
$$x = \ln(1+\sqrt{2})$$
This is our only real solution verified by the fact $e^x > 0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $e^x$ is injective over $\mathbb{R}$. This implies that the sum of the real solutions is $\ln(1+\sqrt{2})$.

However, if we were solving the equation over $\mathbb{C}$ we may consider the negative solution of the quadratic equation (check out the complex logarithm on Wikipedia).
$$e^x=1-\sqrt{2}$$
$$x = \ln(1-\sqrt{2}) = \ln((-1)(\sqrt{2}-1)) = \ln(\sqrt{2}-1) + \ln(-1)$$
By Euler's Formula we know
$$e^z=-1 \implies z = \ln(-1) = (2n+1)\pi i$$
for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus
$$x = \ln(\sqrt{2}-1)+(2n+1)\pi i$$
Note that our other solution for x can also take on infinitely many complex values.
$$x = \ln(1+\sqrt{2}) + 2n\pi i$$
If we try to sum up all these values the series is divergent. But we can just consider the principal value of $\ln(-1) = \pi i$.
Thus, over $\mathbb{C}$ the sum of the principal values of our solutions is
$$\ln(1+\sqrt{2}) + \ln(\sqrt{2}-1) + \pi i = \ln(2-1) + \pi i = \pi i$$

Hope this helped. :)

Comment: A faster route to that might be to say the product of the two solutions to $y^2-2y-1=0$ is $-1$, so if you think there are two solutions to $e^{2 x}-2e^x-1=0$ then you might argue that their product is $\log(-1)$ and the principal value of that is $\pi i$